# Dynamically adding TabButton to TabBar

Tags: qt, dynamic, qml, tabbar

I am trying to add a TabButton to a TabBar dynamically.  My new tab is in a file called Network, and my GWEdit_101 descends from a class with a TabBar.  When the code runs and tries to add the tab it errors on the addItem line below.  I can't figure out the cause/solution.

My file Network.qml is:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

TabButton {
    id: tabNetwork
    contentItem: Text {
        text: qsTr("NewStuff")
        opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        elide: Text.ElideRight
    }
}
```

My file GWEdit_101.qml is:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
GWEdit {

    Component.onCompleted: {
        tabBar.addItem(Network)
    }
}
```

Results in this error

```
"Could not convert argument 0 at"
     "onCompleted@qrc:/content/equipment/gateway/edit/makemodels/GWEdit_101.qml:6"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use [`Qt.createQmlObject`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#createQmlObject-method) since Network is a component, not an item.

```
TabBar {
    id: tabBar
    Component.onCompleted: {
        var tabItem = Qt.createQmlObject('Network{}', tabBar)
        tabBar.addItem(tabItem);
    }
}
```

Fore more information please read: [Dynamic QML Object Creation from JavaScript](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html).

Comment: This generates error that Network is not a type.  (But I do import the directory with Network.qml in it)

Comment: @TSG I am assuming that GWEdit_101.qml and Network.qml are in the same folder, is that correct?

Comment: Network.qml is in relative folder ../tabs/  but I import "../tabs" at the top of GWEdit_101.qml, and Network.qml is in the qrc file

Comment: then use `var tabItem = Qt.createQmlObject('import "../tabs"; Network{}', tabBar)`